# Storing data in the database using jQuery & PHP without a form

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, post

Ok, so I'm trying to store users' key presses in a database, but so far I had no luck. I have the following JavaScript code:

```
$(document).bind('keypress', function (event) {
    $.post('processPost.inc.php', { "valueToStore"  : event.which } );
}
```

Then, I have my `processPost.inc.php` PHP file, with the following code:

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['valueToStore'])) {
    storeIntoDatabase(sanitizeInput($_POST['valueToStore']));
}
```

I know that the event detection itself works, that the `storeIntoDatabase` and `sanitizeInput` functions and everything else works, but I'm **almost certain** that I'm using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/)'s `$.post` in the wrong way (or there's a typo somewhere but that wouldn't be so hard to fix, just a pain in the ass).

I'd like to know how to use it in this specific situation. I've been looking up `$.post` examples and all, and every example I found talks about forms and serializing, but in this case there is no form at all. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Check if `process.inc.php` is in the same directory as the script posting it to (or use an absolute path). Check if the request actually goes through (web server logs, packet dump, etc) and what it returns.

Comment: pressedKeyASCII will have integer keyCode. and you want to insert same integer??? for your info: you can try  `$.ajax({});`   http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Comment: @run Thanks for the tip man, I'll try using `$.ajax`

Comment: umm... $.post and $.ajax will accomplish the exact same thing. I would suspect Etienne is more on the right track. Use Firebug or your browser console to see what data is being sent.

Comment: But, I'm using `$.post` the proper way then?

Comment: According to the doc : The data option can contain either a query string of the form key1=value1&key2=value2, or a map of the form {key1: 'value1', key2: 'value2'} --- Try to remove the quotes around "valueToStore" (that will probably not fix your prob, but it's always good to follow the standard)

Comment: @CronosS thank you man! using `{ valueToStore : event.which }` solved it! I guess the problem were the quotes around valueToStore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the doc: <sup>[[source]](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)</sup>

> The data option can contain either a query string of the form
>   key1=value1&key2=value2, or a map of the form {key1: 'value1', key2:
>   'value2'}

In a map, the key should not be wrapped with quotes:

```
$(document).bind('keypress', function (event) {
    $.post('processPost.inc.php', { valueToStore : event.which } );
}
```